# fetching value from same line and next line

Tags: regex, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have a text file which has data in this format. I want the fetch the doctor's name. May I know what would be the regular expression or any other approach which would handle both the cases

```
The patient is referred by Dr. Zach Foster.


The patient is referred by
Dr. Corey Piccirillo



Output:
Dr. Zach Foster
Dr. Corey Piccirillo
```

I am using the below regular expression for first case then using Spacy to fetch out the name:

```
re(r'.*referred by.*',re.I)
```

For the second case:

```
for line in file:  
   if "referred by" in line:
       print(next(ifile, '').strip())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re(r'by[\n\s](Dr.+\.*)',re.I)
```

Would match both cases in capture groups.

Comment: Thank you! I worked, Just a small update add * after [\n\s] otherwise it is not matching the second case, so
           
                    re(r'by[\n\s]*(Dr.+\.*)',re.I)